# Scala io.source class v object

Tags: scala, class, object, io

I'm following the example below.

In the scala documentation for the package IO there is a source class and source object represented by O and C.Could somebody explain the difference?

I thought "import scala.io.source" imports the source class? but the fromfile method is part of the source object?

For example the source class has the addString() method and the source object has the fromFile() method. When do you use which?

Thanks

```
import scala.io.Source

object Test {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  println("Following is the content read:" )

  Source.fromFile("test.txt" ).foreach{ 
     print 
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The object and the class are more-or-less independent things that happen to have the same name (there are a couple of minor things like implicit resolution where a "companion object" is special). Scala allows you to have a type and a value with the same name, since it will always be possible to tell which you mean from context:

```
class Foo {
  type Bar = Int
  val Bar = "Hello"
}
val foo = new Foo
type baz = foo.Bar
val quxxl = foo.Bar
```

Since they have the same name, importing `Source` happens to import them both.

You use the `object Source` like any other `object`, as per your example. You use the `class Source` like any other `class`:

```
val s: Source = ...
s.addString(...)
```

(Note that if you ever want to refer to the *type* of `object Source`, that's `Source.type` - this is no different from any other `object` (e.g. the type of `Nil` is `Nil.type`; there is no type called plain `Nil`). It's just slightly confusing because there *is* a type called `Source` - the type of instances of `class Source`)

Answer (score 0):

In scala a class can have a [companion object](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/09/companion-object.html) which holds static methods and fields for the class. There is no static keyword in scala. The companion object is not the class of Source.